# Trouble opening file in C++

Tags: c++, io, ifstream

I'm having trouble opening a file for reading, and I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong, maybe something is wrong with how i give my path, but i don't know.

```
/*
output:
Where is the conversion table ?
/Users/awiebe/Documents/Langara\ Assignments/CPSC1160/CURRENCYCODES.txt 
Unable to open file
*/


StringFloatMap readFile(string path)
{
    //fstream filestr ("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
    ifstream filestr;
    const char* cPath = path.c_str();
    filestr.open(cPath);

    if (filestr.is_open())
    {
        filestr.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }
/*…*/
}
```

Comment: cout << "Opening " << cPath << endl;

Comment: Try calling this function with full path (like `/Users/awiebe/Documents/test.txt`). Also make sure that the file exists and that you have write permission on it.

Comment: Write permission really?

Comment: yes, since its opened with write options.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the space character in the path (e.g., you can remove the \ in your filename).

Comment: What escape char - its just a comment

Comment: @AdrianCornish: It appears that the comment at the top is the output after running the program (including a prompt for "Where is the conversion table ?" that we don't see the code for). In that case, alanxz is right, the space shouldn't have a \ before it when entered at an interactive prompt. The easiest solution is to *avoid* using spaces in directory names.

Answer (score 0):

The cPath variable is not needed (but maybe good for debugging)

I would suggest printing the failure message. Add

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
```

and

```
cout << "Unable to open file:" << errno << ':' << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the "\" and give him the path: 
e.g.:

> /Users/awiebe/Documents/Langara Assignments/CPSC1160/CURRENCYCODES.txt

Since you use the string class there is no need to use escape sequences for the whitespaces.